# 'ascii' codec can't decode error while installing .bar package to blackberry device

Tags: cordova, blackberry, blackberry-10

I'm able to build a cordova blackberry app and run it on blackberry emulator

But when I tried to run it on Blackberry Q5 device using the command

`cordova run blackberry10 --devicepass <xxx> --keystorepass <xxx>`

I got the following error

```
[INFO] actual_dname::actual_id::actual_version::result::failure 500 'ascii' codec can't decode 
byte 0xe2 in position 109: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The same error is happening when a sample app created from WebWorks and tried to install it on device

What is this error and how to solve it?

Comment: have you resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I face same issue and i resolve this issue by change the author name from bar-descriptor.xml

**solution 1)**

changed the author simply to "Julian Buss", recreated the debug token, cleaned the project and then I could run it on the device. Problem solved. [click here](https://www.blackberry.com/jira/browse/BBTEN-2754?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel)

**solution 2)**

Remove debug token from your device or simulator please follow below step

1)  goto **Setting->Security and Privacy->Development Mode->** click on **remove debug token button**(This button is display if and only if you have install any debug token )

2)  if you have not install debug token then regenerate debug token and install it.

I hope this will work This solution is work for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, however I'm posting the answer in order to help anyone still facing this issue.

I resolved this issue by changing debug token, I have generated a new one because the issue is related to debug token author name, it was containing a non acceptable characters.

When I changed it, and installed the new debug token, Issue has been resolved.